# QgsVectorLayer not loading correctly

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3, vector-layer

I'm working with PyQGIS and have encountered an issue. While my code successfully creates a new layer (as evident in the screenshot attached), this layer does not load correctly into the project. I'm not sure what's causing this discrepancy. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
def create_and_add_layer(self,layer, layer_name, style_path, shp_path, request, root):
    
    writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(
        shp_path, "UTF-8", layer.fields(), layer.wkbType(), layer.crs(), "ESRI Shapefile"
    )

    if writer.hasError() != QgsVectorFileWriter.NoError:
        print("Erro ao criar o shapefile:", writer.errorMessage())
        return

    # Filtra as feições com base no request fornecido
    features = layer.getFeatures(request)

    # Adiciona as feições filtradas ao shapefile
    for feature in features:
        writer.addFeature(feature)

    # Limpa o writer
    del writer

    # Carrega o shapefile como uma nova camada
    new_layer = QgsVectorLayer(os.path.abspath(shp_path), layer_name, "ogr")
    if not new_layer.isValid():
        print(f"Erro ao carregar a camada: {new_layer.error().message()}")
        return

    if new_layer.featureCount() == 0:
        print("A nova camada está vazia.")
        return
    # # Aplica o estilo à nova camada
    new_layer.loadNamedStyle(style_path)
    new_layer.triggerRepaint()

    # Adiciona a nova camada à raiz do projeto QGIS
    root.addLayer(new_layer)
    #QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)

    print(f"A camada {layer_name} foi adicionada ao projeto.")
```

In the screenshot, you can see the layer is created, but when it comes to loading it into the project, something goes wrong. Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the layer to the project instance before you add it to the layer tree.

[See here](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsProject.html#qgis.core.QgsProject.addMapLayer) for the documentation.

```py
# add the layer to the project, but do not show it in the layer tree
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer, addToLegend=False)
root.addLayer(new_layer)
```